# CSS Images Under text every time

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, position, resolution

I want to ask how to have image under text at the same position even if the window is zoomed out/in. I've done it here in navigation : [www.luxweb.sk](http://luxweb.sk) with the table.. But it's shitty and validator shows me an error. I want to know how to do it better because, i can fix it on my screen resolution but when someone with another will visit my website he'll have it messed up. I'm working on this one : [hetike](http://hetike.dopice.eu) I want to have the social images exactly under the logo. It works with Mozilla fine but chrome.. Please check the code an reply.. Thanks!

HTML

```
    <header>
      <nav id="nav1">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="index.html">References</a></li>
          <li><a href="index.html">Price List</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <span>&lt;&gt;</span>
      <h1>Aways</h1>
<!-- navigacia2 -->      
      <nav id="nav2">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#references">References</a></li>
          <li><a href="#price">Price List</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
<!-- socialne siete -->      
      <div id="socialne">
          <a href="http://twitter.com"><img src="images/tw.png" id="tw" alt="twitter"></a>
          <a href="http://facebook.com"><img src="images/fb.png" id="fb" alt="facebook"></a> 
          <a href="http://google.com"><img src="images/g+.png" id="g" alt="facebook"></a>
          <script src="social.js"></script>
      </div>      
    </header>
```

CSS

```
h1{
  font:50px amplify;
  color:white;
  margin-left:30px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-top:-10px;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #657e94;
}
span{
  position:absolute;
  font:50px amplify;
  color:white;
  margin-top:-35px;
  margin-left:75px; 
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #657e94;
}
#nav1{
  float:left;
  margin-left:205px;
  margin-top:20px;
  display:inline-block;
}
#nav2{
  margin-top:20px;
  margin-left:15px;
  display:inline-block;
}
li{
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left:10px;
}
li a{
  font:12px Calibri;
  color:white;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #466584;
    display:inline-block;
}
li a:hover{
    border-bottom:3px solid white;
    padding-bottom:3px;
}
#socialne img{
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left:15px;
  opacity:0.2;
}
#socialne{
  width:400px;
  margin-left:382px;
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UI elements should be CSS backgrounds, not inline images. Inline images are for content.

For example:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com"><img src="images/tw.png" id="tw" alt="twitter"></a>
```

Should be:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com" title="Twitter" class="twitter"></a>
```

CSS:

```
.twitter {
    display:block;
    background-image:url(images/tw.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:80px;
    height:40px;
}
```

You will need to set the dimensions according to your image size. Also, it's best to put all spacing, padding/margin and font styling on the A-tag, not the wrapping list element.